# How to wait for RPCs from another presenter?

Tags: gwt, block, gwt-rpc, gwt-platform, presenter

Im using gwt-platform and I have 2 Presenters ( MainpagePresenter and SecondpagePresenter). MainpagePresenter is my DefaultPlace.
So, onModuleLoad I am starting to load data from the server part with rpc and saving my data into the client cache. I implemented a PopupPanel to show a loading screen like this:

```
 PopupPanel loadingPanel = new PopupPanel(false, true);

 this.loadingPanel.add(new Label("loading..."));
 this.loadingPanel.center();
 this.loadingPanel.show();
```

So the user can't click on anything before everything is loaded sucessfully.
The Panel will be hidden when `onSucess()` from the rpc is called.

My SecondpagePresenter gets the saved data from the cache `onReset()`.

```
@Override
protected void onReset()
{
    super.onReset();
    this.data = (Data) this.cache.get("Data");
}
```

Everything works fine, but when I am browsing the second page and do a browser refresh, the code of SecondpagePresenter will still be called before my data is received.

The only solution I found so far is to implement a while loop like this:

```
while(cache.get("data") != null)
{
  Window.alert("loading");
}
```

This prevents the code to continue but the user has to click on an "OK"-Button.

So my questions is: Is there a way to block the code from SecondpagePresenter to get called before the data from my MainpagePresenter is loaded successfully?

Comment: You could use the EventBus (the SimpleEventBus should work) to pass custom events like start/stop loading between your presenters. The presenter making the request will use the bus to fire the startloading event, your second presenter will handle that event by actually displaying a loading message. Same with the stop loading.

Comment: Thank you, that will work. Didn't have this in mind. Unfortunately I can't mark your answer as correct.